# Allowing to submit after selecting radio buttons in all multiple choice questions -iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, radio-button

I am Developing an iOS Application in that app i have one screen like below
 [image] i have designed this screen using UITableView for every question with four multiple choice answers is in one row...Now what i want is if user not selected any one radio button in any one question i do not want to allow user to sumbit..After selecting answers in every questions then only i want allow users to submit.
I have tried below code its not working

```
 NSArray *sr;
    sr = _tableViewRef.indexPathsForSelectedRows;
    if(sr != 0 )
    {
        if (selectedArray.count == questionsArr.count)
        {

            [objRef showAlertWithTitle:@"Application..!" message:@"Submitted Successfully" thirdParam:self];

        }
        else
        {
            [objRef showAlertWithTitle:@"Application..!" message:@"please select any one option" thirdParam:self];

        }
    }
```

Please help me on this thank you..

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Its allowing to submit without choosing any option :( Signare

Comment: will u print the value of  selectedArray.count ?.

Comment: create a array of array & store all the four buttons into one array...finally looping it & check your conditions

Comment: what is the name of control of your radio button?is this normal button with adding image?

Comment: You can't use selected rows - the rows won't be selected.  You need to use a something delegation pattern to track the selected item for each row into an array or dictionary; the only allow the submission if all rows have a selected value in the data object

Comment: Thank you Dharma for your response can you please provide some code snippet..because i am very new iOS development.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes it normal button with adding image i have wrote just radio button logic thats it now what i want is without selecting any option in any question i do not want allow user to submit.

Comment: what you are getting in "sr" ? @hani

Comment: Hi Paul Thanks for your response please can you provide any code.

Comment: just check if(sr.count ==questionsArr.count ){//then submit}else{//dont submit}

Comment: @Signare i have used that array to store selected row..

Comment: will you try this  if(sr.count ==questionsArr.count ){//then submit}else{//dont submit} @hani

Comment: yes its not working dear  :(

Comment: kindly provide more code ? @hani

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: i just wrote those code lines only I am very new to this iOS field..can you guys please take few minutes to provide answer in more elaborated way..Thank you guys for your response.

Comment: guys if you dont mind shall i send my sample project to Your mail ids

Comment: please check your email once dear @Signare

Comment: @hani i have send you the code. check it.

Comment: Hey Thank you so much your code worked like champ :) :) Once again Thank you @Signare

Answer (score 0):

Keep a Bool isAnswerSelected in your model object e.g Questions and set to YES when you select any radio button against a question. The submit button code is below. No need to manage two arrays

```
-(void)submitBtn_clicked{

    int count = 0;
    for (Questions *qObj in questionsArray) {

    if (qObj.isAnswerSelected)
        count++;
}

if (count == [questionArray count]) {
    // submit your request
}
else
   // show alert
```

}